# how to update pip's list of installed distributions after installing package through python script?

Tags: python, pip

```
from pip._internal import main as call_pip
# call_pip(['foo', 'bar']) == pip foo bar
```

After installing something using `call_pip(['install', 'package'])` I want to preserve changes in `requirements.txt`:

```
from pip._internal.operations import freeze

with open('requirements.txt', 'w') as f:
  for line in freeze.freeze():
    f.write(line + '\n')
```

But data from `freeze` is outdated as if I ran it before installing/updating new package. I also tried `call_pip(['freeze'])` and redirecting stdout stream into the file, but it didn't fix the problem.

How can I update a list of installed distributions after scripted installation?

Comment: Using pip from within an existing runtime is completely unsupported - don't do that. Bad things happen! You should use pip's CLI from a subprocess instead.

Comment: yeah, calling everything via `subprocess.Popen` solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only supported interface to pip is the CLI. Calling the CLI via a [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) instead should resolve your issues.

Read the ["Using pip from your program"](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program) section in the docs.

> ... you must not use pip’s internal APIs in this way. There are a number of reasons for this ... The pip code assumes that is in sole control of the global state of the program.